# How to list imported modules?

Tags: python

How to enumerate all imported modules?

E.g. I would like to get `['os', 'sys']` from this code:

```
import os
import sys
```

Comment: I do not think it is possible in native Python, but this previous question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572582/return-a-list-of-imported-python-modules-used-in-a-script

Comment: Sometimes (ex: with `ipython --pylab`) python interpreter is launched with predefined modules loaded. Question remains, for how to know the alias used o_O

Comment: For those interested in displaying a list of all modules and their version numbers as a small measure of reproducibility, see the answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703975/is-there-a-sessioninfo-equivalent-in-python

Answer (score 265, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.modules.keys()
```

An approximation of getting all imports for the current module only would be to inspect [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) for modules:

```
import types
def imports():
    for name, val in globals().items():
        if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
            yield val.__name__
```

This won't return local imports, or non-module imports like `from x import y`.  Note that this returns `val.__name__` so you get the original module name if you used `import module as alias`; yield name instead if you want the alias.

Comment: Or you could find the intersection of sys.modules with globals, and do no type testing at all.

Comment: This is the only solution that returns the full module name when you redefine the name of your imported module. For example if you do `import numpy  as np`, this will return `numpy` while the other two suggestions will return `np`.

Comment: If you for some reason need both the module name and the alias, this is available in the `name` variable. Thus to generate the string `import numpy as np` do something like `'import %s as %s' % (val.__name__, name)` where the yield statement is now.

Answer (score 58):

Find the intersection of `sys.modules` with `globals`:

```
import sys
modulenames = set(sys.modules) & set(globals())
allmodules = [sys.modules[name] for name in modulenames]
```

Comment: Maybe use a `frozenset` here instead? - Here's my 1-liner: `frozenset(imap(lambda name: modules[name], frozenset(modules) & frozenset(globals())))`

Comment: The above solution doesn't extract modules which are being imported using the `from` command. For e.g. consider `from scipy.stats import norm` . This doesn't tell me that `norm` module is imported. How can that be incorporated into this?

Comment: @Ujjwal Well, those modules aren't being imported, just their components. If you need everything, just use sys.modules.

Comment: This also doesn't show modules imported as an alias. For example `import sys, numpy as np; set(sys.modules) & set(globals())` just gives `{'sys'}`

Answer (score 41):

If you want to do this from outside the script:

**Python 2**

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script("myscript.py")
for name, mod in finder.modules.iteritems():
    print name
```

**Python 3**

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script("myscript.py")
for name, mod in finder.modules.items():
    print(name)
```

This will print all modules loaded by myscript.py.

Comment: For Python 3, change `.iteritems()` to `.items()` and brackets for the print statement

Comment: Note: It crashes when you are dealing with namespace: https://bugs.python.org/issue40350

Comment: This snipped itself has 204 dependencies on my machine... Is that weird or expected?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_package'     

How?

Answer (score 17):

let say you've imported math and re:

```
>>import math,re
```

now to see the same use

```
>>print(dir())
```

If you run it before the import and after the import, one can see the difference.

Comment: Results include only standard library modules, ex. `math`, `re` and `sys`, which fits the OP's example.  However it fails to include all imported modules, ex. `myapp.client`.

Answer (score 12):

```
print [key for key in locals().keys()
       if isinstance(locals()[key], type(sys)) and not key.startswith('__')]
```

Answer (score 8):

It's actually working quite good with:

```
import sys
mods = [m.__name__ for m in sys.modules.values() if m]
```

This will create a list with *importable* module names.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

This code lists modules imported by your module:

```
import sys
before = [str(m) for m in sys.modules]
import my_module
after = [str(m) for m in sys.modules]
print [m for m in after if not m in before]
```

It should be useful if you want to know what external modules to install on a new system to run your code, without the need to try again and again.

It won't list the `sys` module or modules imported from it.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of contorted answers here, some of which doesn't work as expected on latest Python `3.10`. The best solution for getting the script's *fully* imported modules, but not the *internal* `__builtins__` or *sub-imports*, is by using this:

```py
# import os, sys, time, rlcompleter, readline
from types import ModuleType as MT
all = [k for k,v in globals().items() if type(v) is MT and not k.startswith('__')]
", ".join(all)

# 'os, sys, time, rlcompleter, readline'
```

The result above was inspired by the answer above by [@marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21640/marcin), which is basically taking the union of all the modules *and* the globals:

```py
# import os, sys, time, rlcompleter, readline
modulenames = set(sys.modules) & set(globals())
allmodules = [sys.modules[name] for name in modulenames]
for i in allmodules: print (' {}\n'.format(i))

#<module 'time' (built-in)>
#<module 'os' from 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\os.py'>
#<module 'sys' (built-in)>
#<module 'readline' from 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\readline.py'>
#<module 'rlcompleter' from 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\rlcompleter.py'>
```

Also notice how the *order* of the imports is also reflected in the **1st** solution, but not in the last. However the module path is also given in the **2nd** solution which could be useful in debugging.

<sub>*PS. Not sure I'm using the correct vocabulary here, so please make a comment if I need to be corrected.*</sub>

Comment: How do you take what you've done except put the results in a Pandas dataframe with Package names in one column and versions in another column? I want to be able to track Packages loaded and their versions for reproducibility purposes.

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways to do it, but I would regex the 1st occurrence of the singlequote `'` and what's following.

Answer (score 2):

Stealing from @Lila (couldn't make a comment because of no formatting), this shows the module's /path/, as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
finder = ModuleFinder()
# Pass the name of the python file of interest
finder.run_script(sys.argv[1])
# This is what's different from @Lila's script
finder.report()
```

which produces:

```
Name                      File
----                      ----

...
m token                     /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/token.py
m tokenize                  /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py
m traceback                 /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py
...
```

.. suitable for grepping or what have you. Be warned, it's long!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers listed here require the imported modules to be installed. My use-case was to check if the required modules were installed before loading a file. I used the `ast` package to accomplish this:

```
import ast

def dependency_list(filename:str) -> list[str]:
   with open(filename,"r") as f:
      file_raw = f.read()
   
   # Convert the loaded file into an Abstract Syntax Tree
   file_ast = ast.parse(file_raw)
   modules = []

   # Walk every node in the tree
   for node in ast.walk(file_ast):
      
      # If the node is 'import x', then extract the module names
      if isinstance(node,ast.Import):
         modules.extend([x.name for x in node.names])

      # If the node is 'from x import y', then extract the module name
      #   and check level so we can ignore relative imports
      if isinstance(node,ast.ImportFrom) and node.level is None:
         modules.append(node.module)

   # Get only the parent module for e.g. 'import x.y.z'
   # Use set to remove duplicates
   return list(set([x.split(".")[0] for x in modules]))
```

Answer (score -1):

I like using a list comprehension in this case:

```
>>> [w for w in dir() if w == 'datetime' or w == 'sqlite3']
['datetime', 'sqlite3']

# To count modules of interest...
>>> count = [w for w in dir() if w == 'datetime' or w == 'sqlite3']
>>> len(count)
2

# To count all installed modules...
>>> count = dir()
>>> len(count)
```