# How to batch reload the modules in Python?

Tags: python

I have 2 self-defined packages `pac1` and `pac2`. I **used to import** all the modules **one by one** and **reload them one by one** after change, like so:

```
from pac1 import mod1
from pac1 import mod2
from pac1 import mod3
from pac2 import mod4
from pac2 import mod5

reload(mod1)
reload(mod2)
reload(mod3)
reload(mod4)
reload(mod5)
```

Now, I learn that I **can batch import** the modules and improve the codes to:

```
from pac1 import *
from pac2 import *

reload(mod1)
reload(mod2)
reload(mod3)
reload(mod4)
reload(mod5)
```

But is this the best I can do? **I mean can I reload all the packages in one go?**

**UPDATE1**: I am constantly modifying these modules. So after importing them at the start of the testing, I may need to frequently reload the modified modules to reflect the changes. This is the incentive for me to reload the modules.

**UPDATE2**: This process is not necessarily done dynamically. I just want to make my code more concise by fusing all those `reload()` into one.

Comment: Why do you need to reload them right after importing them?

Comment: @DanielB Because I constantly modify them. Please see editted.

Comment: If the code is just there for reloading during testing, does it really matter if it is concise? You could put it in each of the `pac*` files if you wanted it to be *neater*.

Answer (score 1):

There's a global list of modules in `sys.modules` (in fact, it's a dict). If you want to reload every module which is in the global namespace, try this:

```
import sys,imp
def reloader(globaldict):
    reloadkeys = set(globaldict)&set(sys.modules)
    for key in reloadkeys:
        if imp.is_builtin(key) == 0:
            reload(sys.modules[key])

reloader(locals())
```

Or, if you want to keep track yourself, just create your own list of modules `mymodules`, and append each module to it after importing it. Then you can use a loop to reload each one.

---

Here's a way which avoids reloading builtins without examining `globals`:

```
import sys,imp
def reloader(globaldict):
    for key in sys.modules:
        if imp.is_builtin(key) == 0:
           reload(sys.modules[key])
```

---

Also, you could capture the state of `sys.modules` right after starting the interpreter, and exclude those from your reload using similar boolean operations.

Comment: I think that simply keeping a list of imported modules is the best idea one can get, reloading all modules from sys.modules may be too troublesome - I for instance have about 300 of them, imagine reloading each of them a couple of times...

Comment: @Pawelmhm Note that I specifically provide code which *does not* reload every module in sys.modules.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules)

Alternatively, you could look at how [Werkzeug](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/serving.py) (Flask) does it, which looks like it uses `subprocess` to call itself, or the main portion of the code anyway.

Comment: Link only answers aren't good answers. If the link ever goes dark then the answer becomes useless. Please include the essential parts of the answer here.

Comment: @ChrisF typically I frown on those too... In this particular case I'm assuming that if Github goes dark we have bigger problems ;)

Comment: (I suppose the counter argument to that is that it's perfectly possible for mitsuhiko to delete his branch...) I did try to include the main gist in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you *really* need to reload them, the way you are doing it is best because it is **explicit** (and explicit is better than implicit). It makes it clear whats going on (especially since this is not a normal situation)

If you **really** need to do it dynamically, you can try something like this:

```
import types

for k, v in globals().items():
    if not (k.startswith('__') and k.endswith('__')):
        if isinstance(v, types.ModuleType):
            reload(v)
```

Comment: There's a global list of modules.

Comment: Because there's a global list of modules.

Comment: @Marcin I know, `sys.modules`, but he only wants to reload the ones he's just imported. Trying to avoid reloading *everything*.

Comment: @Marcin, also avoids an infinite loop if the file doing this itself was imported.