# Is there a sessionInfo() equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, r, ipython

Normally I use R, and often when wanting to make things reproduicible I use `sessionInfo()`. The reason for this is that I like to let people know what version of everything I am using and what packages I have installed/loaded and what OS I am on etc, so that its quite clear.

`sessionInfo` returns the version of R, the processor type (e.g. 32/64 bit x86), the operating system, the locale details, and which packages have been loaded.

I am new to python and wondered if there is an equivalent for Python? I'm hoping to use it in an iPython Notebook...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list imported modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules)

Comment: Possibly, but it doesn't give versions, OS, or python version

Comment: @h.l.m There is no builtin/standard way. But, you can try this https://gist.github.com/tahajahangir/5275848#file-pyinfo-py

Answer (score 29):

### Update 2019-03-14

I ended up building a package for this myself called [`session_info`](https://gitlab.com/joelostblom/session_info) to have more flexibility in the output (e.g. show modules imported indirectly through other modules) and to have access to this functionality outside notebooks. It can be installed via `pip install session-info` and used like so:

```py
# Some sample imported modules
import math

import natsort
import pandas
import session_info


session_info.show()
```

which gives you output similar to

```
Session information:
-----
natsort             7.1.1
pandas              1.2.2
session_info        1.0.0
-----
IPython             7.23.0
jupyter_client      6.1.12
jupyter_core        4.7.1
-----
Python 3.9.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 21 2021, 05:02:46) [GCC 9.3.0]
Linux-5.11.13-arch1-1-x86_64-with-glibc2.33
-----
Session information updated at 2021-05-06 09:59
```

---

### Original answer

There is a magic package called [version_information](https://github.com/jrjohansson/version_information) that accomplishes this. Install with `pip install version_information`. (*Note* this extension hasn't been updated in a while, there is a more recent one called [watermark](https://github.com/rasbt/watermark))

```
%load_ext version_information
%version_information pandas, numpy, seaborn
```

Output:

[image]

You could also accomplish something similar using the solution from [How to list imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules) together with `!pip freeze`.

```
#find the names of the imported modules
import types
def imports():
    for name, val in globals().items():
        if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
            yield val.__name__

#exclude all modules not listed by `!pip freeze`
excludes = ['__builtin__', 'types', 'IPython.core.shadowns', 'sys', 'os']
imported_modules = [module for module in imports() if module not in excludes]
pip_modules = !pip freeze #you could also use `!conda list` with anaconda

#print the names and versions of the imported modules
for module in pip_modules:
    name, version = module.split('==')
    if name in imported_modules:
        print(name + '\t' + version)
```

Output:

```
pandas  0.16.2
numpy   1.9.2
seaborn 0.5.1
```

I couldn't figure out how to pass a list with the imported modules (e.g. `modulenames`) to the `%version_information` magic command (all quotation marks need to be removed), so maybe someone can improve this answer by adding that info.

Answer (score 13):

The following will make you part there :

```
In [1]: import IPython
In [2]: print IPython.sys_info()
{'codename': 'Work in Progress',
 'commit_hash': '4dd36bf',
 'commit_source': 'repository',
 'default_encoding': 'UTF-8',
 'ipython_path': '/Users/matthiasbussonnier/ipython/IPython',
 'ipython_version': '2.0.0-dev',
 'os_name': 'posix',
 'platform': 'Darwin-11.4.2-x86_64-i386-64bit',
 'sys_executable': '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python',
 'sys_platform': 'darwin',
 'sys_version': '2.7.6 (default, Nov 28 2013, 17:25:22) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)]'}
```

Otherwise there is no standard way to get the version of imported modules. `pip freeze` will wive you most of installed version of modules on your machine though:

```
In [3]: !pip freeze
Cython==0.20dev
Django==1.4.2
Fabric==1.7.0
Flask==0.9
Flask-Cache==0.10.1
Flask-Markdown==0.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy==0.16
Jinja2==2.7.1
Logbook==0.6.0
...
```

This is something we think should be solved in python before making IPython 'magics' that help with it. This is often requested and we haven't yes find a compromise of what should be done and what would be the requirements.

Comment: I have no clues if it does.

Comment: It's old comment but for others, it does :)

Answer (score 2):

**Conda related answer**

As I regularly install and run jupyter-notebooks with conda (instead of `pip`), I will leave this here in case it is helpful to someone else. At the end of my notebooks I usually have a cell with:

```
!conda list

# packages in environment at /path/to/my/conda_env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_r-mutex                  1.0.1               anacondar_1    conda-forge
appnope                   0.1.2            py39h6e9494a_1    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py39hcbf5805_2    conda-forge
async_generator           1.10                       py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
...
```

Together with `import IPython; print(IPython.sys_info())` it is quite enough to know what was ran in that session.