# Create conda environment from imports

Tags: python, import, conda

I need to create a conda **environment file** from the imports that I am using in my python source code. For the sake of simplicity let's say that this is how the imports in my file look like:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
```

Now I would like to get an `env.yml` file that has the latest `numpy` and `pytorch` defined as imports.

Is there a way to get this done with a oneliner? Or do I have to do it manually? I couldn't find anything relevant in the conda docs.

Comment: This is most likely not possible with any conda command. For one, there is no way to match import names with conda packages (they don't have to agree neccessarily, take `PIL`\`Pillow` as an example). Maybe you could try some regex search in your python files, but that would be a very fragile solution

Comment: Possibly related: [How to list imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4858100/570918) and [Is there a sessionInfo equivalent in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31906216/570918), where the latter has a minor comment about comparing against `pip freeze` or `conda list`. Overall, though, I agree with @FlyingTeller that it's not a solved problem, particularly because import names don't map one-to-one to package names.