# How to import modules that import other modules without using import *

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

Inside the parent class `basehandler.py`, there are several import statements, a constant, and a class:

```
import os
import sys
import cgi
import json

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(foobar)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    pass
```

Another module, `main.py` then imports this parent module with `from basehandler import *`

If we use `from basehandler import BaseHandler` or `import basehandler` so as to avoid the `from foo import *` statement, then the modules that the parent class imports are not received and the program throws an exception.

How do I avoid `from foo import *` while still correctly importing the parent module with the modules that it imports?

Comment: When asking about an error or exception thrown by your program, always include the full text and traceback of the exception, please.

Comment: Well, you could just ``import BaseHandler, os, sys`` but that requires you to know which modules are included in the ``basehandler`` module. Is there a reason why you don't just ``import os, sys`` in both files?

Comment: @moritz:: taht is not how python works - the O.P. is probably making something else wrong.

Comment: That should just work - please put your "main.py" import listing, and the  stacktrace  (error message containign filenames and linenumbers)

Comment: @jsbueno maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly. OP wants to import the imports from the parent module without explicitly writing them out in ``main.py``, right?

Comment: @Moritz: it is right up to there - the "why" the OP might want to do that is the "wrong" part - Python does not need you to import a module's imports in order to work. Your answer is fine otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then the modules that the parent class imports are not received and the program throws an exception.

If your program uses a module then you should import it in the module itself, not in some other module e.g., use `import os` in your program instead of `from foo import *` where `foo` module imports `os` inside.

---

To answer the question in the title: to make all imported modules from another module available without a wild-card import:

```
import inspect 
import foo # your other module

# get all modules from `foo` and make the names available
globals().update(inspect.getmembers(foo, inspect.ismodule)) #XXX don't do it
```

It is like `from foo import *` that imports only modules. The same warnings against wild-card imports are applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules), you can define a function in `basehandler.py` that yields all imported modules:

```
import os,sys,cgi,json
import types

def get_imports():
    for name, val in globals().items():
        if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
            yield val.__name__
```

...and then import that function in `main.py` and use exec to import the relevant modules:

```
from basehandler import BaseHandler, get_imports

for i in get_imports():
    exec "import %s" % i

print os.getcwd() #this will work
```

Sort of a gnarly way of doing it though, is there a specific reason you're not just re-importing the list of modules in `main.py`?

Comment: don't use `exec` unless you must (you don't need it here). The modules are already imported; you don't need to import them again e.g., they are available as `basehandler.os`, etc if you used `import basehandler`. If you need to import modules then use `__import__` or `importlib.import_module` functions. See [my answer for a cleaner solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22603325/4279)

Answer (score 0):

I say there is something else wrong there - 
Importing your "basehandler" module from elsewhere should just work:
the names, modules, classes and objects it needs are bound to its own namespace,
and are present in the `globals` dictionary of any code defined in that module - 
regardless of you getting it with a `from basehandler import BaseHandler` statement.

Please, post your full traceback so that people can find out what is actually happening there.