# What is the best way of listing all imported modules in python?

Tags: python, module, interactive

Usually, after doing numerical SciPy/NumPy calculations in the interactive mode for several hours, a bunch of modules become to be loaded.

Are there any good ways to see the list of imported modules from the interactive python command line?

Thanks!

Comment: import sys; sys.modules.keys()​​​.  For a more refined solution see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sys.modules`:

```
import sys
print '\n'.join(sys.modules)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Pip

```
pip freeze
```

Using:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

will save all the modelues in a text file.

Comment: That lists all *installed* modules, while the question is about listing the modules currently *imported* in a running process.