# How to know what modules where loaded by a module in python

Tags: python

I have a loaded module:

```
module = importlib.import_module('foo.bar.module')
```

How do I get a list of the modules loaded by 'foo.bar.module'?

Comment: Do you want to get all modules from this module or only new ones?

Comment: Are you talking about all the imports from any file that is also imported into module? Can you add an example?

Comment: The modules imported by 'module' when loaded.

Comment: `dir(module)` would give you that?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking to do is a `dir` on the module.

Something like this:

```
module = importlib.import_module('foo.bar.module')
print(dir(module))
```

This will give you everything that is inside `foo.bar.module`

Comment: I can't find the loaded modules with dir.

Comment: Are you looking for something more like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules