# How to I list imported modules with their version?

Tags: python

I need to list all imported modules together with their version. Some of my code only works with specific versions and I want to save the version of the packages, so that I can look it up again in the future.
Listing the names of the packages works:

```
modules = list(set(sys.modules) & set(globals()))
print modules
```

But if I now want to get the version of the list items it doesn't work with:

```
for module in modules:
    print module.__version__
```

Is there a way to address the `.__version__` command with a string, or have I to go another way to get the name and the version?
In other questions only the names of the modules are addressed: [How to list imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules)

Comment: That's because you are saving only the modules *name* in that `modules` list. In any case: note that the `__version__` attribute is just a convention. Many modules don't have that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have a list of strings of the module name, not the module itself.  Try this:

```
for module_name in modules:
    module = sys.modules[module_name]
    print module_name, getattr(module, '__version__', 'unknown')
```

Note that not all modules follow the convention of storing the version information in `__version__`.

Answer (score 3):

One of the issues I have had with huge legacy programs is where aliases have been used (`import thing as stuff`).  It is also often good to know exactly which file is being loaded.  I wrote this module a while ago which might do what you need:

spection.py

```
"""
Python 2 version
10.1.14
"""
import inspect
import sys
import re

def look():

    for name, val in sys._getframe(1).f_locals.items():
        if inspect.ismodule(val):

            fullnm = str(val)

            if not '(built-in)' in fullnm and \
               not __name__     in fullnm:
                m = re.search(r"'(.+)'.*'(.+)'", fullnm)
                module,path = m.groups()
                print "%-12s maps to %s" % (name, path)
                if hasattr(val, '__version__'):
                    print "version:", val.__version__
```

Using it:

```
import sys
import matplotlib
import spection

spection.look()
```

Gives (on my system):

```
matplotlib   maps to /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/__init__.pyc
version: 1.3.1
```

You will note that I omit builtins like `sys` and the spection module itself.

Comment: Great idea! But I would have returned the values as a dictionary, rather than just print them (yes, I know, the OP used print, but in this case it's a utility function)...

Comment: @SwedishOwlSerpent:  the original code did just that, I modified it to be closer to the question.  It wouldn't take much to change it.

Comment: @cdarke this code works only with top level package right? If I import `matplotlib.pyplot` for example, I don't get the matplotlib version. Do you have a current solution working on this?

Comment: @gc5:  Not sure if that is feasible since the module being imported is not `matplotlib` but `pyplot`.  I have to think on this, I'll post a comment here to you if I get a version working.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks. I actually implemented a small package to do this based on the code provided in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396275/41977). The package is `py_session` (https://github.com/fbrundu/py_session). If you can let me know if you find some issues/things we can improve on that. Thanks,

Comment: @gc5 - maybe you should publish it on PyPI ?