# How to list imported modules and version in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, version

I am aware that several questions on SO seem to address this problem (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267791/how-to-i-list-imported-modules-with-their-version), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules)). However, the reported solution seem not to work in my code (python 3.6.5). In the first case, fewer modules are printed, in the second case a lot more information is displayed (`sys.modules.keys()`).

Is there an easy way to display all imported top modules together with versions (through `__version__`) in a similar fashion as `sessionInfo()` in [R](https://github.com/r-lib/sessioninfo)?

Comment: The first answer you linked to worked for me (Python v3.6.1). What exactly didn't work for you with the code in the first answer? What does _". . . fewer modules are printed . . ."_ mean?

Comment: @ChristianDean I imported at least 8 modules, but only 2 are shown when I run the code of the first answer

Comment: @ChristianDean my problem was with aliases, adapting this solution to Python3 works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38268153/41977

Comment: Okay @gc5, since the solution on that question worked for you, I went ahead an dupe-hammered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import sys
for module in sys.modules:
    try:
        print(module,sys.modules[module].__version__)
    except:
        try:
            if  type(modules[module].version) is str:
                print(module,sys.modules[module].version)
            else:
                print(module,sys.modules[module].version())
        except:
            try:
                print(module,sys.modules[module].VERSION)
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: To add to this solution, if you want to omit builtins I suggest looking at this answer (to adapt for Python3): https://stackoverflow.com/a/38268153/41977

Comment: I put together a very simple package to do this using your suggestion: https://github.com/fbrundu/py_session

Comment: This didn't work at all. Only lists a few internal modules with a version string attached.