# Pip freeze packages that are actually imported

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have a (Django) project with lots of imports that I started without virtualenv. Is there a way to

```
pip freeze
```

only the Python packages that are actually imported somewhere in the project, i.e. they are required by my project?

```
pip freeze
```

would list all the packages installed in my system, but I would only need those ones that are used by my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list imported modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules)

Comment: you can start with `grep -r 'import' ./`

Comment: @Fi3: the problem is that this won't give exact package names with version numbers

Comment: Have a look at [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs). Also, not what you're looking for here, but you may like [pip-tools](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools), as well.

Comment: @jonafato: pipreqs looks interesting. It seems to miss lots of packages though... For me, if I navigate to every subdirectory, it would find the imports, but will miss some of them when running from the project root.

Answer (score 2):

A manual solution could be

Find the packages with grep

```
grep -r import ./*/*[.py] > j.t
```

Iterate all the lines in `j.t` with python

```
fromIndex = line.find('from')
importIndex = line.find('import')
if fromIndex != -1:
    return = line[fromIndex + 5 : importIndex - 1][5:]
else:
    return = line[importIndex + 7:]
```

Remove all the duplicates

Pip freeze in the virtual env for find the version number

Pip freeze out the virtual env for find the other version number