# Get dependency file to host Jupyter notebook on Binder?

Tags: python, dependencies, jupyter, conda

I am trying to export my dependencies to a `requirements.txt` or `environment.yml` file for `pip` or `conda` respectively - in order to host a Binder notebook.

How can I get **only** the dependencies that my notebook is using?

When I tried `pip freeze` or `conda env export`, I get all my installed packages, which leads to errors when building the Docker environment.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try watermark:

Install:

```
pip install watermark
```

Then, in your notebook:

```
# Load the extension
%load_ext watermark

# import your libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Determine the dependency version
%watermark -p numpy,matplotlib,seaborn
```

The results will look like this:

```
numpy 1.14.3
matplotlib 2.2.2
seaborn 0.9.0
```

Comment: More discussion in this vein is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49199019/8508004).