# MyBinder.Org - Jupyter Notebook interactive function not showing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49199019/4544928) to build a `requirements.txt` file for my Jupyter notebook. I then put both the `ipynb` and `requirements.txt` file in a Git repo and published it to [Binder](https://mybinder.org/). As I understand, this should give me an interactive version of my notebook which I can share with people for them to play around with.

The published Binder can be found [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/Thevesh/Edexcel-Aggregator/master).

Does anyone know why the `interactive` bit is not showing? Specifically, the sliders.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the extension that allows the sliders, namely ipywidgets. There is an example of using ipywidgets presently [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyter-extension) among the Binder example template repos. (If that repo gets altered, I was talking about [this specific commit](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyter-extension/tree/c821b862098a0f71dddb59dce799af960fb21430).)
Right now the extension gets enabled separately for JupyterLab vs the classic interface. If you just want to have your launches default to the classic interface, you can leave out the JupyterLab-related enabling.