# Explanation on globals(), and getattr() with (Python 3 within Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

---

I was looking for a way to get all the import version numbers within Jupyter's notebook, and I ran into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428931/package-for-listing-version-of-packages-used-in-a-jupyter-notebook). The code is working well, however, I would like to understand the globals(), and getters() part of the code.

What I understand so far is that m.name and m.version are being joined together as a string. Then for every m in globals() which referred to all the library is being printed, however, what throws me off is what's in the if statement. The getattr() returns the value of the named attribute, so in this case, it'll return the name of the library. I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly.("`if getattr(m, '__version__', None))"` )

```
# In[1]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

print('\n'.join(f'{m.__name__} {m.__version__}' for m in globals().values() if getattr(m, '__version__', None)))
```

Output

```
pandas 1.1.1
numpy 1.19.1
tensorflow 2.2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

`globals()` returns a dictionary of all the global variables. When you import a module, the module name becomes a global variable whose value is the module object.

System modules have a `__version__` attribute that contains the version number of the module.

It's using `getattr(m, '__version__', None)` to avoid getting an error when it tries to access the `__version__` attribute of objects that don't have that attribute. The third argument to `getattr()` is a default value to return if the attribute doesn't exist. This allows the generator to filter out all the objects that *aren't* modules.