# Python check if module is in use in another file

Tags: python

I want a function to set the random seeds for several known packages.I'd like to create a library function which calls:

```
tf.set_random_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
random.seed(seed)
```

, but only if actually needed.  In some cases the caller will be part of a program that uses numpy and in others it won't.

I want a single function, in its own importable file, which will set the random seed of various packages, but not to import the package unless used by the caller.

I can easily work-around this by inserting the method in each caller's file.  But, I'm curious if there is a way to do what I want to do.

Can I somehow query the calling function and determine "In your scope, has numpy been imported"?  If so, this function would call np.random.seed.

Comment: There is an answer in this question related to checking imports of a module from outside of that module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules

Comment: Perfect.  I'll write it out as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Luke DeLuccia pointed me in the correct direction.  For future readers, The code might look something like this:

```
import sys
def set_pseudoseeds(seed):
    # random
    try:
        module = sys.modules['random']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        module.seed(seed)
    ...
```

Thanks Luke!