# How do I identify imported packages in python code

Tags: python, pip, python-module

it frequently happens that I get single python files or whole projects where I need to identify which modules are imported - mostly for license clearing purpose.

How can I do this in an - as complete as possible - way? I am aware of the pipreqs tool but it somehow does not list all modules in the final report, although it seems to identify all of them -> according to the debug logs.

I'm fine with investing time into developing a tool - so a strategy on how to do this would be great.

Thank you

Comment: would it be something like this [How to list imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4858123/1248974)

Comment: Not not really. I want to get the modules by just analyzing the source (in the best case automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, if you are just interested in licenses of your dependencies:

If you get access to a project, I reckon there must be something like a `requirements.txt`, [Pipfile](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv), [pyproject.toml (Poetry)](https://poetry.eustace.io/) or similar which contains all the required packages. Or you should have access to the running environment, where all packages are installed.

With that assumption, you could use [pip-licenses](https://pypi.org/project/pip-licenses/) to identify the licences of all **installed** dependencies. Usage is quite simple:

```
$ pip install pip-licenses
$ pip-licenses --with-urls
Name    Version  License  URL
Django  2.0.2    BSD      https://www.djangoproject.com/
pytz    2017.3   MIT      http://pythonhosted.org/pytz
```

I often had the problem, that the license wasn't exposed in the `setup.py` file. Therefore I had to visit the project page itself to get the license.