# Python: How to list imported modules

Tags: python

In Python calling the **import** function brings in a module to give a program access to its namespace of classes, functions and variables.

```
import os
import sys

print(os.name)
print(sys.implementation)
```

Is there a way to list which modules have already been imported in a program?

```
>>> list_imports()
sys
os
```

And if so, is there a way to figure out the version of the imported module?

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules?answertab=votes#tab-top) has an answer for the exact same question.

Comment: Yep, try `dir()`

Answer (score 0):

`sys.modules` is the closest you'll get. Modules following spec will have a `__version__` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just use sys library

```
import sys
sys.modules.keys()
```

Comment: This list so many modules. Not the one that are imported.