# List all the python modules imported by a project

Tags: python-3.x, linux, shell, python-module

I am running my projects on python=3.6 and i want to list all the modules imported by the python scripts present inside this project/repo/directory so i can build a project specific requirements file for future use.
Help me with a script to traverse down the directory tree to list the modules or any available python module to do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules)

Comment: You can use pip freeze to list all libraries installed.

Comment: pip freeze will list all the libraries installed in the os / virtual-environment but i wan't to list the libraries and packages specific to the project

Answer (score 2):

I came across the pipreqs package, which generates a requirement.txt file based on the import statements of the project.

**Installation:**

```
pip install pipreqs
```

**Usage:**

```
pipreqs /path/to/project
```

pipreqs will automatically generate a requirements.txt file in root folder of your project.

**Limitation:**
Pipreqs uses imports of projects to generate a requirements.txt file. So, it is very important to note that, pipreqs will not include the plugins required for specific projects. You need to add plugins information manually in a requirement.txt