# requirements.txt file in heroku

Tags: python, heroku, bots, telegram, requirements.txt

I made a telegram bot in python that scraps a website for anime updates. I tried to deploy it on Pythonanywhere but the website is not on there whitelist. Now, I want to try Heroku but it made me confused with the requirements.txt file. what should I write in that file?

Comment: `requirements.txt` file is a file that contains all the dependencies of your python program. Se this: [https://stackoverflow.com/tags/requirements.txt/info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/requirements.txt/info)

Comment: @JorgeMorgado I think you can make your comment here as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requirements.txt` is a file that contains all the dependencies of your python program. Se this: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/requirements.txt/info

The dependencies will be written like this for example:

```sh
typer==0.3.1
```

There are some ways to do this automatically. I believe `pip freeze` gives you all the external dependencies of your environment. By external I mean all the modules that are not build-in.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61628623/11915595). This shows you how to create automatically the `requirements.txt` with only the external dependencies your project uses.