# How to reload locally imported functions/files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, restart, modularity

I want to make changes to a file, and I want it to reflect in real-time without restarting my program and losing all the memory states.

Suppose I imported a function like this:

```
from A.B.C.foo import bar
```

There are multiple imports like this in multiple files.

How do I reload all of them? (Or say, just one)

Comment: `importlib.reload(sys.modules['module_name'])`

Comment: So is it `reload(sys.modules['A.B.C.foo'])`? Or `reload(sys.modules['A.B.C.foo.bar'])`? Or `reload(sys.modules['bar'])`? And how do I go about filtering local files from sys.modules to avoid explicitly mentioning everytime?

Answer (score 0):

**To reload one module**: In older versions of Python there was a builtin `reload()` method.  It's been moved to the `importlib` module, but for awhile it also lived in the `imp` module.

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: from importlib import reload

In [3]: reload(pandas)
```

**To reload a bunch**:  If you know which modules you want to reload, you can of course just call `reload()` as much as you need.  To detect all of the modules which have been imported is actually a bit tricky though.  [A limited version which will get all modules imported by saying `import mod` is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384926/6796731):

```
import sys
modulenames = set(sys.modules) & set(globals())
allmodules = [sys.modules[name] for name in modulenames]
```

Comment: So is it `reload(A.B.C.foo)`? Or `reload(A.B.C.foo.bar)`? Or `reload(bar)`?

Comment: `reload()` understands things at the module level.

Comment: The comment to the linked answer says it doesn't work for imports using `from`. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules/19384926#comment88026919_19384926)

Comment: that is correct.  That is why I noted that it'll only work when you say `import module`.

Answer (score 0):

To reload function:

```
import sys, importlib
importlib.reload(sys.modules['A.B.C.foo'])
from A.B.C.foo import bar
```