# How to determine which python modules rely on another module?

Tags: python

How can i determine which module(s) in my virtualenv rely on the '[py](https://pypi.org/project/py/)' module so that I can consider replacing the reliant module(s) ?

There are existing SO questions which will show you which modules a module is dependent on ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049328/how-to-find-what-modules-are-used-by-a-python-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules), for instance) but I want the opposite to find which modules are dependent upon a given module.

The '[py](https://pypi.org/project/py/)' module is the subject of a CVE https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-42969 which in turn triggers a 'High Severity' Dependabot error.

My current work environment requires such reports to be fixed.

The release of 'py' which is the subject of the error report is the latest release and the repos is in maintenance mode so it seems the current release is the last release.