# List all dependencies of a Python file

Tags: python, import, dependencies

Lets suppose I have a Python file(A.py) which is dependent on some pip modules (lets say numpy, tensorflow) and some other user modules in the package (lets say B.py, ../otherfolder/C.py etc.)

I want to list all these dependencies. I tried searching a lot but couldn't find any tool for this. Also it would be a bonus if it could also recursively list B.py and C.py dependencies. Thus at last I shall have the list of all all pip modules and user modules required to run A.py.

snakefood was one such tool for this purpose but it was last updated 13 years ago and doesn't support Python3

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this? [How to list imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules)

Comment: Yeah but that only lists pip modules. Not user defined local modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use the `ModuleFinder`. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38019082/3921917) and the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/modulefinder.html) for it.