# How to get list of imported items in python file

Tags: python

I want to get list of imported items in file

Example
I have a file

```
# file1.py
from mod1 import a
from mod2 import b, c

print(a)
```

I want a function that takes path of the file  `foo("file1.py")`
and returns the following

```
{
    "file1.py": [
        "mod1": ["a"],
        "mod2": ["b", "c"]
    ]
}
```

Is there existing python library to solve my problem?

What python lib do you recommend to analyze python code?

Comment: Please, check [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules)

Comment: Your output requirement is not a valid Python structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
{
    "file1.py": [
        "mod1": ["a"],
        "mod2": ["b", "c"]
    ]
}
```

is impossible the items in the list would need to be dictionaries so more like:

```
{
    "file1.py": [
        {"mod1": ["a"]},
        {"mod2": ["b", "c"]}
    ]
}
```

```py
import ast

def get_imported_items(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        tree = ast.parse(file.read(), filename=file_path)

    imports = {}
    for node in ast.walk(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Import):
            for alias in node.names:
                module_name = alias.name
                if module_name not in imports:
                    imports[module_name] = []
        elif isinstance(node, ast.ImportFrom):
            module_name = node.module
            if module_name not in imports:
                imports[module_name] = []
            for alias in node.names:
                imports[module_name].append(alias.name)

    return {file_path: [{module_name: items} for module_name, items in imports.items()]}

result = get_imported_items("file1.py")
print(result)
```

should do the trick just specify the path