# How to import several files from specific folder in python

Tags: python, import

I am new to Python and have a problem that I don't know how to solve

I need to write a module (directory `C:/Python`) that is able to import and execute all `.py` files that are located in some other folder (for example `C:/Python/Dir`).
I know how to access to directory (`sys.path.append('C:\\Python26\\Dir')`) but how do I make a loop that is able to import all `.py` files from this folder?

Comment: os.walk can help you look here... http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use the [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) built-in function together with [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html):

```
os.chdir(path)
for file in glob.glob('*.py')
    __import__(file[:-2])
```

Comment: sorry, I'm new here, I don't know the rules.I hope now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you import all the files in a directory by some glob, how could you access these modules contents without a name? Maybe there is a way to get all imported modules even if they're anonymous (see [Return a list of imported Python modules used in a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572582/return-a-list-of-imported-python-modules-used-in-a-script) - not an easy task), but isn't it easier to list them explicitly?

Maybe you can just create some `__init__.py` file in your directory and explicitly list imported files there with appropriate module names.

Comment: I guess he writes some debug tool or something; you can't really expect from pydoc to create files in protected directories, can you? About the names, he can just make a list and use `getattr(globals(), name)`.