# Finding user defined modules imported

Tags: python, module

I found the module [modulefinder](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/modulefinder.html) that:

> can be used to determine the set of modules imported by a script.

However, when I do the example test to my script, it just check for the base modules, and doesn't report the modules it imported that are not base (the "-" was my addition to proper readable format):

```
Loaded modules:  

- tokenize:  LPAR,PseudoToken,ENDMARKER  
- heapq:  sort,izip,_nlargest  
- __future__:  __module__,getMandatoryRelease,division  
- copy_reg:  _inverted_registry,_slotnames,__all__  
- sre_compile:  _optimize_unicode,isstring,_sre  
- _collections:    
- cStringIO:    
- _sre:    
- functools:  wraps,partial,WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS  
- random:  WichmannHill,_sin,_exp  
- cPickle:  
- __builtin__:  
- subprocess:  __module__,STDOUT,__str__  
- dummy_thread:  __module__,__enter__,__exit__  
- gc:  
- cmd:  do_help,__module__,prompt  
- __main__:  PREDICTORS_CFG_DIR,sequence,tearDown  
- operator:   
- array:  
- select:  
- _heapq:  
- _threading_local:  current_thread,__module__,__new__  
- abc:  __module__,_InstanceType,_abc_invalidation_counter  
- _bisect:  
- posixpath:  _varprog,sameopenfile,splitext  
- _random:    
- os2emxpath:  pardir,realpath,stat  
- tempfile:  _TemporaryFileWrapper,_set_cloexec,_candidate_tempdir_list  
- errno:  
- pprint:  __module__,format,_StringIO  
- binascii:   
- token:  DEDENT,LPAR,ENDMARKER  
- sre_constants:  REPEAT_ONE,makedict,AT_END_LINE  
- re:  __module__,finditer,_expand  
- _abcoll:  __module__,Container,__isub__  
- collections:  __repr__,OrderedDict,_make  
- ntpath:  pardir,realpath,exists  
- threading:  _BoundedSemaphore,_sleep,Semaphore  
- opcode:  hasjrel,hasconst,EXTENDED_ARG  
- _struct:    
- _warnings:  
- math:  
- shlex:  __module__,get_token,file  
- fcntl:  
- genericpath:  isdir,stat,commonprefix  
- stat:  S_IWRITE,ST_MTIME,S_IRGRP  
- string:  ascii_lowercase,upper,__module__  
- warnings:  __module__,filterwarnings,once_registry  
- UserDict:  __module__,popitem,pop  
- inspect:  CO_VARARGS,formatargvalues,findsource  
- repr:  aRepr,__module__,repr_list  
- struct:  _clearcache,__doc__  
- sys:  
- pwd:  
- imp:  
- getopt:  opt,__module__,short_has_arg  
- readline:  
- copy:  _copy_with_copy_method,__module__,_deepcopy_atomic  
- ConfigParser:  optionxform,InterpolationError,set  
- bdb:  __module__,get_file_breaks,clear_bpbynumber  
- types:  __module__,IntType,TypeType  
- strop:  
- _functools:  
- keyword:  iskeyword,main,kwlist  
- thread:  
- StringIO:  __module__,readlines,getvalue  
- bisect:  insort_right,bisect,bisect_left  
- pickle:  EMPTY_DICT,NEWTRUE,TypeType  
- signal:  
- traceback:  print_stack,print_exception,print_last  
- difflib:  _count_leading,heapq,_namedtuple  
- marshal:  
- linecache:  updatecache,clearcache,__all__  
- itertools:  
- posix:  
- doctest:  REPORT_UDIFF,get_doctest,_parse_example
- unittest:  parseArgs,assertNotEquals,__str__  
- time:  
- sre_parse:  _PATTERNENDERS,SRE_FLAG_UNICODE,AT_END  
- os:  pardir,__module__,sep  
- pdb:  do_enable,help,help_run  
- dis:  hasjrel,hasconst,HAVE_ARGUMENT
```

When my module have just this importations:

```
import os
import unittest #User-Defined
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser #User-Defined


from common import RNASPACE_DIR, TEST_DIR_NAME, DATA_DIR_NAME, \
                   TEST_USER_DIR_NAME, WORKSPACE_DIR, SEQ_FASTA_SUFFIX, \
                   TEST_PROJECT_NAME, SEQ_DIR_NAME, SEQ_TXT_SUFFIX, \
                   PREDICTORS_CFG_DIR, PREDICTOR_CFG_SUFFIX, OUTPUT_DIR_NAME, \
                   TEST_RUN_NAME, OUTPUT_FILE_SUFFIX, REFERENCE_DIR_NAME, \
                   REFERENCE_FILE_SUFFIX
#User-Defined

import sys 
path_rnaspace = "/bi/opt/RNAspace/rnaspace_sources/rnaspace/rnaspace/"
sys.path.append(path_rnaspace) 

from rnaspace.core.sequence import sequence #User-Defined
from rnaspace.core.conversion.gff_converter import gff_converter #User-Defined
from rnaspace.core.conversion.csv_converter import csv_converter #User-Defined
from rnaspace.core.conversion.fasta_converter import fasta_converter #User-Defined
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572582/return-a-list-of-imported-python-modules-used-in-a-script) I found some solutions but or I can't apply them or they have some problems or don't work.

How can I obtain which user defined modules are imported?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the example closely you will see that `modulefinder.ModuleFinder` reports on modules imported rather than just modules for which an import statement is present. THat's because one module can import others, which in turn can import others, and so on.

I suspect your program, primarily as a result of importing `unittest` (which is a complex module), is indeed importing all those modules. If you don't believe that, modify the program to print out the keys to `sys.modules`, which is an easy way to find out what modules have been imported.

Comment: Yes, but how can I filter it to just the ones I defined like whatever is needed to for rnaspace.core.sequence import sequence?