# Python : counting module imports?

Tags: python, counting, metaclass, diagnostics

I am a mid end python developer at an animation studio, and have been presented with a unique diagnostics request ;

**To assess what code gets used and what doesn't.**

Within the sprawling disorganized structure of Python modules importing modules :
I need to count the python modules that are imported, and possibly at a deeper level, find which methods are called.

As far as finding out which methods are called, I think that would be easy to solve by writing my own logging metaclass.

*However, I'm at loss to imagine how I should count or log module imports at varying depths.*

Thanks for any ideas you may have.

Comment: How about reading through all the modules and matching lines which start with `import` and `from` keywords?

Comment: perhaps related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572582/return-a-list-of-imported-python-modules-used-in-a-script

Comment: Have a look at [vulture](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vulture/0.5). I never used it, but maybe it gives you some hints about dead code.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/snakefood

Comment: Thanks user2085282, but in my case I want to log modules that are actually used, not just imported. Will edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: Which python version are we talking about here?  The import mechanism has undergone a whole lot of changes from 2.7 to 3.4+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a way to exercise the code, you can run the code under [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage).  It's normally used for testing, but its basic function would work here: it indicates what lines of code are run and what are not.

Comment: Thanks! I have not looked at "vulture" or "snakefood" yet, but Coverage seems to be pretty close to what we need. I love the HTML report function.