# Getting explicit imports from a source file

Tags: python, python-import, python-internals

#### Question:

Is there a module or a recommended way to get all the explicit `import` statements from a Python source file?

#### My research so far:

I tried using this gem of a module: [modulefinder](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/modulefinder.html). The problem in my case is that this lists *all* of the modules ever used by the source file, including all the implicit and implied modules recursively used.

I am looking for a way to just get the imports that the source file explicitly import, and *not* the implicit/recursive ones.

#### Example:

Taking this one right out of the docs:

```
#bacon.py
import re, itertools

try:
    import baconhameggs
except ImportError:
    pass

try:
    import guido.python.ham
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Now the modulefinder code:

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder

finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script('bacon.py')

print 'Loaded modules:'
for name, mod in finder.modules.iteritems():
    print '%s: ' % name,
    print ','.join(mod.globalnames.keys()[:3])

print '-'*50
print 'Modules not imported:'
print '\n'.join(finder.badmodules.iterkeys())
```

Output:

```
Loaded modules:
_types:
copy_reg:  _inverted_registry,_slotnames,__all__
sre_compile:  isstring,_sre,_optimize_unicode
_sre:
sre_constants:  REPEAT_ONE,makedict,AT_END_LINE
sys:
re:  __module__,finditer,_expand
itertools:
__main__:  re,itertools,baconhameggs
sre_parse:  __getslice__,_PATTERNENDERS,SRE_FLAG_UNICODE
array:
types:  __module__,IntType,TypeType
---------------------------------------------------
Modules not imported:
guido.python.ham
baconhameggs
```

#### Output that I am looking to get:

```
Loaded modules:
re
itertools
guido.python.ham
baconhameggs
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Can't you just do this with a regular expression?

Comment: Do you care about the hackier ways to import things? (e.g. `__import__`)

Comment: Have you read [this question and its anwers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572582/return-a-list-of-imported-python-modules-used-in-a-script)? I think it's the same you're asking.

Comment: @thefourtheye I was having that as the very last resort.

Comment: @katrielalex the source files this would be used on use various sort of import statements and not just `__import__`

Comment: @matagus that question does ask for something similar to what I am looking for. Thanks for the link. I am looking for more directed recommendations still.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #modulefinder.py
    import filename 
    print dir(filename)
```

Where filename is the module that contains the 'explicit' imports.
This unfortunately displays your functions names too.

Comment: Thank you. That is a straightforward way to do it, and I totally missed that `dir` lists imported modules too. Great catch. I might have to go into the returned list and test the items for modules though.

Comment: One additional risk I would like to avoid, using this  method, is that the module needs to be imported first.